# Expected value of a product of two ReLU functions

Tags: expected-value, neural-networks

Let assume $\theta,\theta'\in R^d$ (are two fixed $d$ dimensional real-valued vectors) and $x\sim N(0,I_d)$ (is a d-dimensional random vector comes from standard normal distribution). Now, I am wondering about the quantity

$$E_{x}[\sigma(\theta^Tx)\sigma(\theta'^Tx)],$$
where $\sigma$ is the ReLU function defined as $\sigma(z):=\max (0,z)$ for real-valued $z$.  Basically I am interested to know the expected value of the product of two ReLU functions. Any help would be appreciated.
I am also wondering if maybe some conditions are needed for $\theta,\theta'$ for the integral to make sense?

Comment: The integral exists for all $\theta, \theta'\in \mathbb{R}^d$ by the monotonicity of $E, \sigma$ and Cauchy-Schwartz:

$$E[\sigma(\theta^T x) \sigma(\theta'^Tx)]\leq E[\sigma(\|\theta\|\|x\|)\sigma(\|\theta'\|\|x\|)]=\|\theta\|\|\theta'\| E[\|x\|^2]<\infty$$ since $x$ is a standard normal.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help.